# Simplest way to fetch the file from FTP server (on-prem) & put into S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, aws-lambda

As per my project requirement, I want to fetch some files from on-prem FTP server & put them into a S3 bucket. Files are of size 1-2 GB. Once the file will be put into the FTP server folder, I want that file to be uploaded to S3 bucket. 
Please suggest the easiest way to achieve this?

Note- Mostly the files will be put into FTP server only once in a day, hence i dont want continuously scan the FTP server. once the files will be uploaded to S3 from FTP server, i want to terminate any resources (like EC2) created in AWS.

Comment: Can a server in the public internet access your on-prem FTP server?

Comment: No, server in public internet cant access my FTP (on-prem) server

Comment: Then I don't see how you can do a "pull" architecture (i.e. having a resource on AWS grab the file).  Something on-prem will have to do a "push" to AWS.  Except for S3 I don't think anything else in AWS would be involved.

Comment: I think you could create an agent on your FTP server that will upload the files every N seconds/minutes/hours/Etc using the AWS CLI.  This way you're avoiding external access to your FTP server.  Another approach is a Lambda function for pulling process, but like you said the FTP server doesn't allow external access.

Answer (score 2):

### These are my ideas:

- I think you could create an agent on your FTP server that will upload the files every N seconds/minutes/hours/Etc using the AWS CLI.  This way you're avoiding external access to your FTP server.
- Another approach is a Lambda function for pulling process, but like you said the FTP server doesn't allow external access.
- Create a VPN between your on-prem and the cloud infra, create a Cloudwatch event and through a Lambda execute the pulling process.

**Here you can configure a timeout:**
[image]

- Create a VPN between your on-prem and the cloud infra, from your FTP server upload the files using AWS CLI (pay attention to `sync` option).  Take a look at this link: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/accessing-vpc-endpoints-from-remote-networks/
- With Jenkins create a task to execute a process that will upload the files.
- You can use Storage gateway, visit its site here: https://aws.amazon.com/es/storagegateway/

Comment: I thought of option 3, but I have doubt in that case, if the file transfer will take more than 5 mins, then will the process be terminated?  Also can you pls tell me, how the SFTP or FTPS will work in this scenario? ( i mean which all additional configuration i will have to do in oder to implement SFTP)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we solved it.

Enable S3 acceleration on your S3 bucket. This is very much needed, since you are pushing large file.

If you have access to the server install aws cli and perform a sync on the folder to s3 bucket. AWS CLI will automatically sync your folder to bucket. This way if you change any of  your existing files, it will keep in sync with S3 bucket. This is ideal and simplest way if you have access to the server and able to install aws cli.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration-examples.html#transfer-acceleration-examples-aws-cli

`aws s3api put-bucket-accelerate-configuration --bucket bucketname --accelerate-configuration Status=Enabled`

If you want to enable for specific or default profile,

`aws configure set default.s3.use_accelerate_endpoint true`

If you don't have access to ftp server in your premisis, you need an external server to perform this process. In this case you need to perform a poll or share file system, copy the file locally and move it to s3 bucket. There will be lot of failure points with this process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good resource.  Can you make reference to the pricing of s3 Transfer Acceleration: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/